# How can I show messages in WooCommerce custom shipping plugin?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, aramex

I am building an Aramex Shipping Plugin for WooCommerce Shopping Cart. I can set the calculated amount by using the `add_rate` method, but if there is any *Error Response* from the API, I am not able to show this message in the WooCommerce checkout.

Is there any way to show string messages in the WooCommerce checkout?

Comment: Could you grab the error and then use the `woocommerce_before_checkout_form` filter to echo it?

Comment: Have you solved your issue ? If yes, could you please post how have you integrated the plugin or any link for reference ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wc_add_wp_error_notices` for set error message.

This Example

```
if ($response) {
$rate = array(
    'id' => $this->id,
    'label' => 'Label for Shipping Method',
    'cost' => 10
);
// Register the rate
$this->add_rate($rate);

} else {
wc_add_wp_error_notices(new WP_Error(1,'error in get response from webservice'));

}
```